# How to make search term occurrences readable by Assistive Technology without shifting the focus to each search term?

Tags: accessibility

I am looking for suggestions to make 'Search within document' accessible. It's similar to Ctrl + F on a web page. Let's say someone types a word and hits enter, the search terms gets highlighted one by one but focus remains on the trigger element. So the highlights are visual. How to make the occurrences readable via SR without making changes to the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of information would you want to convey to the screen reader user?  If you find the term in the middle of a paragraph, how would you want to indicate the location to the screen reader user?  If the term is found in a link, would you give them the full link name and where it is on the page?

JAWS (screen reader) has a search dialog but it doesn't highlight each term.  It finds the first occurrence and moves the screen reader focus to the element that contains the occurrence.  F3 would find the next occurrence.  So I'm not sure the UX of a visual concept of highlighting the found string translates well to a screen reader.  You'd really want to move the screen reader focus to the found location so the screen reader user can explore the context around it.

If you really want to use your visual concept, then you'd need an [`aria-live`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-live) area to announce how many matches are found and to describe where the current match is located.

Comment: That makes sense. Programatically displaying the number of search term occurrences and appending and prepending text around search term might complicate a simple functionality unnecessarily. 
Shifting focus to the Search term occurrences on tabbing and adding 'Skip to Search region' consistently in the document sections sounds like a good alternate?